# Java文字列をきれいにそろえる方法教えてください

Tags: java

```
壱万円　３枚
五千円　１枚
千　円　１枚
五百円　１枚
百　円　０枚
```

こちらのように、文字三つと二つきれいにそろえたいです
お願いします。

Comment: System.out.printf, String.formatでぐぐる。

Comment: コンソールプログラムでの話ですか？ 文字列の出力書式的なものでエクセルでいうような両端均等揃えのような書式制御は標準では無かったように思いますので自分で作成する（必要な位置にスペースを割り振るようなプログラム）必要があると思います。